# Exactly once producer slow

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have a kafka producer that needs to be able to produce approx 1m events per minute.
Events cannot be duplicated nor go missing

Below are my configs

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaProducerConfig {

    @Value("${kafka.server.producer}")
    String server;

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
        config.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, server);
        config.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
        config.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
        config.put(ProducerConfig.TRANSACTION_TIMEOUT_CONFIG,120000);
        config.put(ProducerConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG,60000);
        config.put(ProducerConfig.ENABLE_IDEMPOTENCE_CONFIG, "true");
        config.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "all");
        //config.put(ProducerConfig.TRANSACTIONAL_ID_CONFIG, "KafkaSpeedProducer");

        config.put(ProducerConfig.COMPRESSION_TYPE_CONFIG, "snappy");
        config.put(ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG, "200");
        config.put(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, Integer.toString(256 * 1024));
        config.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_IN_FLIGHT_REQUESTS_PER_CONNECTION, 5);
        config.put(ProducerConfig.BUFFER_MEMORY_CONFIG, Integer.toString(8192*4 * 1024));
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(config);

    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {

        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }

}



@Service
public class KafkaTopicProducer {
    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

    public void topicProducer(String payload, String topic) {

        ProducerRecord<String, String> producerRecord = new ProducerRecord<String, String>(topic, null, null,
                payload);

        kafkaTemplate.send(producerRecord);
 
    }
}
```

with this setup i am able to achieve 3.9m events per minute which is perfect.
However from reading to achieve proper exactly once i need to implement transactions.

added

```
config.put(ProducerConfig.TRANSACTIONAL_ID_CONFIG, "KafkaSpeedProducer");
```

to the configs and change the topic producer as follows

```
@Service
public class KafkaTopicProducer {
    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

    public void topicProducer(String payload, String topic) {
      kafkaTemplate.executeInTransaction(kt->kt.send(topic, payload));
        
         
    }
}
```

With this setup i am now getting 1800 events per minute which is terrible.

1.Are transactions needed for this use case?
2.Is there anyway to improve this to get better speeds if it is needed?

Comment: 1. what is usecase?

Comment: These are financial transactions that are being posted into a real-time ledger for reporting etc.